# why "django.forms.widgets has no attribute RadioFileRender" excetpion occured?

Tags: python, django

I am a newbie to django and djangocms , when i try to install djangocms's addon aldyrn_bootstrap3 ,my command is

```
python manage.py migrate aldryn_bootstrap3
```

the following error shows

```
es\aldryn_bootstrap3\models.py", line 26, in <module>
from . import model_fields, constants
File "C:\Users\shikw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
packages\aldryn_bootstrap3\model_fields.py", line 26, in <module>
from . import fields, constants
File "C:\Users\shikw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
packages\aldryn_bootstrap3\fields.py", line 8, in <module>
from . import widgets, constants
File "C:\Users\shikw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
packages\aldryn_bootstrap3\widgets.py", line 10, in <module>
class ContextRenderer(django.forms.widgets.RadioFieldRenderer):
```

AttributeError: module 'django.forms.widgets' has no attribute 'RadioFieldRender
er'

Django (1.11.10)
django-cms (3.5.0)

i seems that 'RadioFieldRender' has been removed.  can somebody help me

Answer (score 0):

Did you mentioned aldryn_bootstrap3 inside INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py

Answer (score 0):

I found this: https://github.com/aldryn/aldryn-bootstrap3/issues/157. Guess it is not compatible with the current Django version. I hope they will fix it soon.